# How to fill two different colors in Custom Shape?

Tags: java, android

I have created the custom shape in android project. here is code,

**curvedShape.xml:-**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <stroke android:width="4dp" android:color="#ffffff" />
    <padding android:left="7dp" android:top="7dp"
            android:right="7dp" android:bottom="7dp" />
    <gradient android:centerColor="#ffffff" android:startColor="#32CD32" android:endColor="#ffffff"/> 
</shape>
```

**main.xml:-**

```
<View   
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft = "10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight = "10dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/curvedshape"/>
```

In shape,gradient attribute gave start color as green, that filled green color vertically. but i want to fill the color like the below image, fill color in horizontal in half shape.
How to do that?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use layer-list and draw two shapes in XML:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >   
    < item>
            < shape
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:shape="rectangle" >

           <stroke android:width="4dp" android:color="#ffffff" />

        </shape>
    </item>      
    <item>
        <shape
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:shape="rectangle" >

            <stroke android:width="4dp" android:color="#7CFC00" />
        </shape>
    </item> 
</layer-list>
```

Edits :
you have just use this gradient attribute in your xml 
`< gradient android:angle="-90" android:centerX="0.5" android:centerY="0.5" android:centerColor="#ffffff" android:startColor="#32CD32" android:endColor="#ffffff"
 />`

I have use this and this show similar shape required by you:

```
 < shape
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:shape="rectangle" >
 < gradient android:angle="-90" android:centerX="0.5" android:centerY="0.5" android:centerColor="#ffffff" android:startColor="#32CD32" android:endColor="#ffffff"
 /> 
 < /shape>
```

Comment: It's not working, second item only taking for whole view. please can you give any other idea?

Comment: @Andal replace your gradient tag with specified by me in edits of this answer

Comment: i have replace gradient tag with specified your code. but it will display only second shape.

Comment: @Andal also remove stroke from your xml

Comment: Now filled color but in top filled as dark ending position of color filled as light color, please can you give any idea to fill the color like above mentioned image?